# Comparison of strings using variables always false (in Batch)

Tags: parsing, batch-file, for-loop, trim

In my current folder, I have a file named `backup(yyyy-mm-dd).7z`
I need to keep that `length` variable even though here it is a constant.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "a=.\backup"
set "b=yyyy-mm-dd"
set "length=19"

for %%f in (.\*) do (

    set "fullpath=%%f"
    set "trimpath=!fullpath:~0,%length%!"

    set trimpath
    echo trimpath=%trimpath%

    if %trimpath% == %a%(%b% echo this is equal
)
```

I have 2 questions regarding that code:

1. Why can I see the value of trimpath when I call `set trimpath` but not directly with `%trimpath%`?
2. Why is my condition false? What should I do to get it true?

Comment: 1. using delayed expansion with `!trimpath!`

Comment: 2. Use double quotes as follows: `if /i "!trimpath!" == "%a%(%b%" echo thisisequal` (and in this command `set "fullpath=%%f"`  as well), in addition to the foxidrive's hint. Also note the `/I` switch.

Comment: @foxidrive @JosefZ You were right guys. I needed to replace `%trimpath` with `!trimpath!` and use the double quotes. The `\i` switch is optional in my case because I want a "case-sensitive" comparison and there will never be only numbers. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution after following @foxidrive and @JosefZ advices!

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "a=.\backup"
set "b=yyyy-mm-dd"
set "length=19"

for %%f in (.\*) do (

    set "fullpath=%%f"
    set "trimpath=!fullpath:~0,%length%!"

    echo trimpath=!trimpath!

    if "!trimpath!" == "%a%(%b%" echo this is equal
)
```

If you need to test the solution, just create a file named `backup(yyyy-mm-dd)` in your current folder.